Auto-fill form fields in clean() method
I use model form for editing records in DB.
I have some business logic for auto-fill attributes, which should happen after passing validation of some business rules.
In some cases, that auto-fill is based both on instance initial attributes values and current form fields values. For example, different rules apply whether it was a change of some attribute or not.
Note: I have no such cases when auto-fill based on other models except one that model form based on.
So my question: Is it correct to auto-fill attributes in form clean() method?
After reading a few various sources, I'm not sure I fully understood if it's acceptable and if it is, in what cases.
A few words why it's not convenient for me to separate validation and auto-fill:
My case is that I have quite complex validation rules and almost every time these rules passed, I need to do some auto-filling. For now I have 2 methods, one in form clean() method for validation, and one in form save() method for auto-filling. Every time I need to change business rules, I should make changes in both these methods. It's not very convenient and besides that can lead to slowing down of "validate-save flow" (maybe minor, but still).
Edit: I understand that it's hard to understand from my poor writing what I'm exactly asking, so I tried to write a simple example what is happening:
For example, our model have "status" attribute, which can be "open" or "closed". As well as some other attributes, for example, "start_date" and "end_date".
case 1: initial status was "closed" and new - "open". Let's assume we don't need any validation here and can just set "start_date" to "today".
case 2: initial status was "open" and new - "closed". Let's assume here we have a business rule, which requires that "end_date" should be filled by user. So here we need a validation of "end_date".
What I'm trying to say, is that I have many business rules, and often 'need for auto-filling' or 'validation errors raise' - logically should be determined in same code blocks.
For now I have 2 methods. First one is placed in form clean() and does a validation. Second one is placed in form save() and does auto-filling. My concern here is that these two methods are strongly dependant on each other logic (for every change in business rules I should check code of both methods and make adjustments). It's very inconvenient, easy to make mistake, hard to write tests (to some degree) and I'm pretty sure I'm missing some best practice here.

It would perhaps help if you give an example. Auto-filling is strictly speaking possible in the cleaning process, but often not the best idea.

tnx for feedback, i'll try to add an example

Express your imagination with real examples.
What input is received from the form, and what data do you want to return through it?

In each case, you don’t notify the user about what was filled correct?

well, if validation fails, then I notify user using standard form errors. but if validation passed, then all possible auto-fill should never raise any errors, so user just gets message about updated record
